# Java native function called without loading library

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface, linphone

This is a GitHub link of a JNI wrapper class implementation in linphone-Android(A Voip SDK).

https://github.com/samueljero/linphone-mediastreamer2/blob/master/java/src/org/linphone/mediastream/video/capture/AndroidVideoApi5JniWrapper.java

As you can see, a native function 'putimage' is declared and used without loading the library using System.load or System.loadlibrary.

I believe that in the JNI approach, the JVM should be able to find the native function implementation on run time. And System.load and System.loadlibrary do that job. But how is it possible to do without loading the library like that?

Comment: How does that process start the JVM?

Comment: I didn't understand your question. These wrappers will get build into an aar locally. And later will be used in android java code. From there, everything gets build into an apk.  I am new to the entire native programming. I thought ART, DVM and JVM works in the same way on JNI.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a requirement to call `System.load` or `System.loadLibrary`. You can used different means of registering native code.

By default, you can export `JNI` symbol by building shared library and loading it, but it's possible to do something else.

Let's say you have native code (`C`) that calls `Java` code by creating `JVM`. In turn, `Java` code calls native code.

**Java**

```
package recipeNo052;

public class Main {

  public static native int addOne(int a);

  public static void displayMessage() {
    System.out.println("Hello from Java");
    System.out.println(
      "I am calling method without System.load: " + Main.addOne(1));
  }
}
```

Now, let's say in your `C` code you have something like this (note that native function has "normal" name - no `JNI` based prefixes, etc.)

**C**

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL addOne(JNIEnv *env, jclass obj, jint a) {
  return a + 1;
}
```

once you have your `JVM` created, you can do something like this

```
JNI_CreateJavaVM (&jvm, (void **) &env, &vm_args);

....
....

static JNINativeMethod methods[] = {
  {"addOne",    "(I)I", (void *)&addOne}
};

...
...

jclass cls_Main = (*env)->FindClass (env, "recipeNo052/Main");

...
...

(*env)->RegisterNatives(
  env, 
  cls_Main,
  methods, 
  sizeof(methods)/sizeof(methods[0]));

...
...
```

and now, whenever you call `Main.addOne` you actually call `addOne` function from your `main` code.

**Sample code**

```
> git clone https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook.git
> cd jnicookbook/recipeNo052
> make all
> make test
> make clean
```

You should get something like this

```
> make test
lib/recipeNo052_main
Hello from Java
I am calling method without System.load: 2
```

You can find repo here: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook.git

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying. I didn't know that it was possible to initiate JVM from native code. Today, I figured out the issue. It is not mandatory to load the library from the class definition itself. In fact, you can load it with different methods before using that class in your code. JVM will link it to the class later through the mangled naming convention.

Comment: Yes, you can, for example, use `LD_PRELOAD`. In general, you have to make sure that symbols are visible to `JVM`.